# Two-dimensional Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having the following problem and after numerous discussions with a mathematician and a theoretical physicist I thought that maybe it a good idea to post it here. Maybe someone has a good idea:

Here's the problem:

There are two unknown functions $T_1$ and $T_2$ for which the time derivatives

$\dot{T_1}(T_1,T_2,t)= \left\{\begin{array}{cl} \frac{T_2-T_1}{R_1}, & \text{if controller 1 is }\bf{off}\\  \frac{T_2-T_1}{R_1}+P, & \text{if controller 1 is }\bf{on}  \end{array}\right. $

and

$\dot{T_2}(T_1,T_2,t)= \left\{\begin{array}{cl}  \frac{T_1-T_2}{R_1} -\frac{T_2}{R_2}, & \text{if controller 2 is } \bf{off}\\\frac{T_1-T_2}{R_1} -\frac{T_2}{R_2} +Q, & \text{if controller 2 is  }\bf{on} \end{array}\right. $

are known functions of T1, T2 and the time t. P and Q are constants.

Controller 1 switches to $\bf{on}$ when T_1 reaches its maximum value $T_{1_{max}}$ and switches to $\bf{off}$ when $T_1$ reaches its minimum value $T_{1_{min}}$.

Controller 2 switches to $\bf{on}$ when T_2 reaches its minimum value $T_{1_{min}}$ and switches to $\bf{off}$ when $T_1$ reaches its maximum value $T_{2_{max}}$.

And here is my question:

Is it possible to transform the integral $\int{T_1}dt$ into an integral $\int{\text{two-dim. Jacobian } T_1 dT_1dT_2}$ ? 
 I guess for the the solutions I would have to find an expression like $dt= f(dT_1, dT_2)$

The purpose of all this is to generalize the one-dimesional problem (which is easily solvable through a Jacobian)

$T=T(t)$      is a unknown bijection within [0, $\delta t$]

$\dot{T}$ is a known expression

then $\int_0^{\delta t}{T(t)}dt$ = $\int_{T_{min}}^{T_{max}}{T(t)\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial{T}}dT}$

where $\frac{\partial{t}}\partial{T}$ = $\frac{1}{\dot{T}}$

to two dimensions.

Thanks for your input!
Alex